# Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction<{},any>'

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular8

I am upgrading my project from Angular 5 to 8 and I see this issue.
What am I doing wrong?

```
this.pinService.savePinComment(this.pinComment, this.pinService.participantPin).subscribe(res => {
    this.pinService.modeForPinComment.next({ readOnly: false, isInEditMode: false });
  });
```

PinService.ts

```
public savePinComment(model: PinComment, pin: string) {
  const body = JSON.stringify(model);
  const options = Utilities.getApiAuthorizedRequestOptions();
  const requestUrl = `${this.pinCommentsUrl}/${pin}/${model.id}`;
  return this.http
    .post(requestUrl, body, options)
    .pipe(
      map(res => this.extractPinComment(res))),
  catchError(err => {
    return this.handleError(err);
  });
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's extraordinary this compiles.  Your issue is that you close the pipe at the map, and then the `catchError` is just running outside of the pipe.

Here's the correct code:

```
.pipe(
  map(res => this.extractPinComment(res)), // removed a parenthesis
  catchError(err => {
    return this.handleError(err);
  })
);
```

Comment: My bad, Thanks Daniel for helping me out, appreciate it